# duplicate row in many to many relationship mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  many to many relation problem in this scenario

Table : customer_master

```
+---------+-----------+
| cust_id | cust_code |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | S00333    |
+---------+-----------+
```

Table : customer_supply_chain

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------------+
| supply_cust_id | cust_code | supplye_cust_code |
+----------------+-----------+-------------------+
|              1 | S00333    | HI00001           |
|              2 | S00333    | MA00010           |
+----------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Table : customer_vehicle

```
+----------------+-----------+------------------+
| cust_vehicl_id | cust_code | vehicle_model_id |
+----------------+-----------+------------------+
|              1 | S00333    |              161 |
|              2 | S00333    |              162 |
+----------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Mysql Query is :

```
SELECT
  cv.vehicle_model_id,
  csc.supply_cust_code AS suppl_code
FROM customer_master cm
  LEFT JOIN customer_supply_chain csc
    ON csc.cust_code = cm.cust_code
  LEFT JOIN customer_vehicle cv
    ON cv.cust_code = cm.cust_code
WHERE cm.cust_code = 'S00333'
```

result of query

```
+------------------+------------------+
| vehicle_model_id | supply_cust_code |
+------------------+------------------+
|              161 | HI00001          |
|              162 | HI00001          |
|              161 | MA00010          |
|              162 | MA00010          | 
+------------------+------------------+
```

our desire output is

```
+------------------+------------------+
| vehicle_model_id | supply_cust_code |
+------------------+------------------+
|              161 | HI00001          |
|              162 | MA00010          |
+------------------+------------------+
```

The problem is in every row is repeated by `supply_cust_code` and `vehicle_model_id`,

We try with distinct and group by and other fixes (show in stack overflow) but not work,

If we use group by so we can not get all data and we don'T want to use `group_concat` , we cant rectify the problem ,
We just try to make getting all row but not repeated

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: There are no duplicates in your results. It's just normal, you have several possibilities of Vehicle and Supplier . The question is: you want only one row for what ? Vehicule or supplier? But that raise another question : What are the rows supposed to be removed ? Show and explain the results you want.

Comment: And which output do you expect if customer_supply_chain will consists of 3 rows whereas customer_vehicle still have 2?

Comment: @ThomasG and @ Tim Biegeleisen i update my question and add my desired output please check again.

Comment: @Sergey yes if there is max record in supplier then its not issue in vehicle repeat,

Comment: @GMS Sorry, i didn't understand your answer. Could you give example of output?

Comment: @Sergey i already add my desired output in my question please check it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GMS i meant output for the case when count of rows are uneven

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are getting those duplicates, because the sample data does not support it, but you can either try using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cv.vehicle_model_id,
                csc.supply_cust_code AS suppl_code
FROM ...
```

Or you can try grouping on the model ID and supply customer code:

```
SELECT cv.vehicle_model_id,
       csc.supply_cust_code AS suppl_code
FROM customer_master cm
LEFT JOIN customer_supply_chain csc
    ON csc.cust_code = cm.cust_code
LEFT JOIN customer_vehicle cv
    ON cv.cust_code = cm.cust_code
WHERE cm.cust_code = 'S00333'
GROUP BY cv.vehicle_model_id,
         csc.supply_cust_code
```